# Umbraco Maganav - add option to upload image

Tags: menu, nested, umbraco7

Currently I am using Umbraco 7.8.1 for my CMS, I have a requirement of designing nested menu. What I want is, CMS user can design nested menu with Menu text, Link and Image. I know **Maganav** package can work with this but it doesn't give option to upload image. I have also tried **Nested Content** datatypes, but it just mashes up in UI !

Can anyone please help me out from this? Any other supported packages or any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "mashes up in UI"?

Comment: I just created another DocumentType and added as Nested content.